# HTML page, hidden div show up

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing this effect with HTML, bootstrap2, and JS. 


Sorry I don't have a working example yet, and did not find an example could demo anywhere, so I will just describe what I want to do in detail.

It is a plain HTML page visually contains two "cards" aligned vertically. The card could be just a `div` contains a `textbox` and a `button`. Initially only one card is visible and the other one is hidden, and I hope the page size fits only one card. After I click the button on card 1, the page hight should get greater to fit in two cards, and card two shows up.

My uncertain part would be: How do I hide a div initially and show it by clicking a button? (I want the page size fits any number of cards) I am not too familiar with web development, so a working example will be very helpful!

Thank you!

Comment: It all comes down to manipulating the css `hidden` attributes. You can add an event handler for the click event on the two divs and toggle this attribute on and off. Take a look at jQuery.show() and jQuery.hide()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice example I have just cooked up.

You should already have your **HTML & CSS** set up, but here is what I used.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Card 1 -->
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button id="clickMe">Show second card</button>
</div>

<!-- Card 2 -->
<div style="display: none;" id="newCard">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button>Do nothing</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{ /* A bit of random styling */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 30px 15%;
    background: skyblue;
    border: 2px solid #EEE;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

**Vanilla Javascript**

```
var button = document.getElementById('clickMe');  // 1
var newCard = document.getElementById('newCard'); // 2
button.addEventListener('click', function() {     // 3
   newCard.style.display = 'block';               // 4
});
```

**INFO**

> 1. Get the element that has a `ID` of `clickMe`
> 2. Get the element that has a `ID` of `newCard`
> 3. Listen for when the `clickMe` element is `clicked`
> 4. When `clickMe` is `clicked` set the display of `newCard` to `block`

**Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T4yxz/**

Answer (score 1):

You could rely jQuery to show/hide elements. Set a div element to hidden and onclick event of a button should hide/show your elements.

Take a look at jQuery's api:

http://api.jquery.com/show/

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Simple example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mrkre/KKLZ4/

```
$('#HideHidden').click(function() {   
    $(".hidden-div").hide();
});

$('#ShowHidden').click(function() {   
    $(".hidden-div").show();
});
```

You would then need to manipulate the css for height elements.

Answer (score 0):

On Page load you start out with the div hidden, by setting the css styling for that element as display:none. When you want to show that element, add a .show() event to the button click function.